# How do I access MAPI properties using EWS Java API?

Tags: java, exchangewebservices, ewsjavaapi

I am working to process Exchange emails and figure out when an e-mail was read. I believe this information can be obtained using one of the MAPI Properties (PR_LAST_MODIFICATION_TIME).

Can someone help me to get this property value using EWS Java API? I could find equivalent samples for C# but not for Java.

Answer (score 1):

Isn't EWS Managed API the same for C# and for Java? `Item` class has property `LastModifiedTime` and you can use it with all objects of classes derived from Item so I really do not see what you having problem with.

Sample code:

```
Item item = Item.Bind(service, itemId);
if(item.LastModifiedTime > lastCheckTime)
{
    ProcessItem(item); //here you put your code of course
}
```